# Changing "#" from URL formatting in GWT-Platform

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform, gwtp

Is this possible to change "#" character or change URL format to "/param/:value/param2/:value2" for GWT project when we are using GWTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gwt-pushstate to get rid of the hash bang #

Answer (score 0):

The '#' charakter is defined in the html standard to navigate to an anchor in the same page. This is used by the history management in gwt. Please have a look at the w3c docs:
[fragment-uri](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/intro.html#fragment-uri)

You can not change this!